# Thai language insert issue using with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have thai string `98/10 ม.8  ถนนริมน้ำ`
If i can insert this string it is inserted like `98/10 ม.8��ถนนริมน้ำ`

I have used

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SET NAMES tis620");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET character_set_results=tis620");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET character_set_client=tis620");
mysqli_query($conn, "SET character_set_connection=tis620");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set using character set `utf8_general_ci`.
Or set database column and table with `utf8_general_ci`.
[check how to set character set using query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-applications.html)